# JMS Commit between the routes - I want to commit the transaction between the routes in Camel

Tags: transactions, apache-camel, spring-jms

I am using JMS Transaction in camel

I have two routes

```
from("jms:queue:test).process(new Processor(Exchange exchange){
   //place the message to hdfs
   //using hadoop fs api
}).to("direct:ssh")

from("direct:ssh").to(sshCommand)
```

what I want is after sending the message to direct ssh route commit the JMS transaction. Don't wait for the direct ssh route result.

Currently, Transaction is committed only when my ssh command gives the result, Is it possible to commit in between

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do the above operation instead of using direct I used seda

```
from("jms:queue:test).process(new Processor(Exchange exchange){
   //place the message to hdfs
   //using hadoop fs api
}).to("seda:ssh")

from("seda:ssh").to(sshCommand)
```